# Display different content for all the rows of a table in twitter bootstrap popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, popover

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: hearings">
    <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: ID, event: { mouseover: $parent.displayHearingsCaseID }" class="hearingIDCell"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

On mouse over event of the span element, I am generating content dynamically that I want to show on popover.
Since the span element will have same id/class for all the records, the popover is showing same content for all the rows. How can I display different content for all the rows ?

```
$('.hearingIDCell').popover({ trigger: 'hover', content: caseIDString, title: "Case ID" });
```

The value for string caseIDString is generated for every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout passes the event object as the second parameter to the handler function.

```
 $(event.currentTarget).popover({ content: caseIDString, trigger: 'hover', title: "Case ID" });
```

Above line now shows me different content for all the rows that is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

When a mouseover occurs, `displayHearingsCaseID` will be called with the element of `hearings` associated with that row as its first argument. Presumably its fields contain the information you need, so you could use

```
$('.hearingIDCell').popover({
   trigger: 'hover', content: data.caseIDString,
   title: "Case ID"
});
```

where `data` is the argument passed to your event handler.

Comment: The value in caseIDString is calculated for every row inside displayHearingsCaseID function. Its a local variable inside the function. It won't be available within data argument.